# Why is explainability not one of the criteria for publication?

Tags: publishability

A paper is eligible for publishing in reputable journals in general if it satisfies the criteria objectivity, reproducibility and (optionally) novelty.

But why are they not considering Explainability as a criterion? Although the model proposed in the paper satisfies the above mentioned three metrics but not explainability, then how can it be considered as a contribution to field?

PS: Low "explainability" means proving something works without explaining how it works. See also "[Interpretability](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/interpretability.html)"

Comment: If it didn't satisfy explanability, how did it get accepted by peer reviewers?

Comment: Some subfields of computer science has wide acceptance without explainability.

Comment: @hanugm I think that you mean a different kind of explainability. A paper containing a bunch of complicated equations without explanations will certainly be rejected by every reputable journal. The type of explainability that you talk about appears to be "using these insights from the problem domain, we found that this new approach works", with an in-depth explanation of the approach, but without a (possibly statistical) analysis on why exactly it works. Is it so?

Comment: @DCTLib  Yeah, I am talking about the second part of explainability you mentioned. Say neural networks....

Comment: What's explainability? Do you mean accessibility?

Comment: @user2768 I mean proving something works without explaining how it works.

Comment: @Anyon True, since the both terms are used interchangeably, I used explainability.

Comment: So experimental results should not be published until they are well understood?

Comment: i edited your Q to add soft definitions and link to explainability/interpretability explanation.

Comment: There are huge realms of knowledge where we know *what* happens, but not *why* it happens... are you proposing that that should not be publishable?

Comment: You specifically mentioned neural networks - is this what the core of the question is aiming at? If so, I agree that we have a *severe* problem in computer sciences with people publishing thousands of black boxes in different sizes and shapes, and nobody dares to even try and understand what they are doing. Well, at least https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explainable_Artificial_Intelligence has gained *some* attention recently. People are probably noticing by now that all this grew out of hand...

Comment: @fqq Then why restriction on objectivity if some subjective results (from experiments) are reproducible?

Comment: @Flyto With similar argument we can't rule out *objectivity* as a criteria?

Comment: Academia is broken anyway, so...

Comment: From the comments and answers, it seems to be clear that a *proper* answer highly depends on the *field* that you are referring to. It may not be a bit too late to narrow down the question in this regard. But (at *some* risk of creating a "duplicate"), you might consider a question that is more specific to the field that you are interested in, maybe also elaborating what "explainability" means (or is supposed to mean) in this field.

Comment: Who are these monolithic "they" who rigidly adhere to 3 criteria? Your question seems like it is based on a caricature.

Answer (score 31):

Coming especially from a biomedical sciences perspective,

> I mean proving something works without explaining how it works.

(from a comment describing what is meant by 'explainability')

this would be an absolute disaster for science. Many results are not explainable according to that criteria; many treatments are known to be successful without being explained (some examples: anesthesia, paracetamol, anti-depressants). If we waited until findings were understood before publishing, science would move a lot more slowly.

If you had a black-box image processing algorithm that, for example, beat the state of the art in tumor detection in processing MRI images, that result would be very interesting and publishable without being able to explain the black-box. In fact, it would likely be unethical to *not* publish such a finding.

However, that also doesn't mean that everything that is published is "true" and definitive: further confirmation by repeated studies, applying a consistent algorithm to new/independent data sources, etc is necessary to build consensus. Those aspects need not present a *barrier* to initial publication, however. To the contrary, it's important to publish even negative results to facilitate future meta analyses.

Certainly, a paper which can explain some phenomenon has a lot of merit and value, and is better than work that cannot provide such an explanation, it's just that "explainability" cannot be a *required criterion*.

Comment: For the field of medical science your statement may be true, but that particular example from your last paragraph strikes a chord for me. Currently, we're seeing a *flood* of papers in computer science that apply "deep learning"/"neural networks" to a variety of highly specific problems, and do not say more than "It works (but we don't know why)". Many people are publishing like mad and literally *do not have the slightest idea of what they are doing* - even though that may seem hard to believe for other fields. Really, cf. https://xkcd.com/1838/ : If it looks right, it will be published.

Comment: @Marco13 Indeed, though of course people still need to be cautious of https://xkcd.com/882/ - that shouldn't be a barrier to publishing, though, it should be a barrier to how studies are interpreted and how results are validated on independent data. I should make clear that I have in mind things like paracetamol which are in wide use, definitely effective, and yet...still oddly not well understood.

Comment: Superconductivity would be another example.  New superconductors may require hundreds of papers before they are explained.

Comment: @Marco13 It's a horrible problem really.  How can we know that the neural networks actually work if we don't know how they work?  I know they had an AI that could check chest X-rays for tuberculosis, and while they did better than human x-ray technicians, many of the false positives it found were correctly assessed as negative by humans. The issue was the AI knew the xrays were coming from a hospital, it had learned this meant he or she was sicker, and this biased the test to think it was more likely tuberculosis.  If you can't explain what patterns it's finding, how do you know they are real?

Comment: @BryanKrause The comment indicates that the barrier for something that can be published *at all* seems to be much higher in the field that you are referring to - specifically when you talk about "validation" and "independent data". In some branches of computer science, people are really throwing *any* data into *any* neural network and produce *any* result, and then use 4 pages to argue that it "looks right". It is like sampling the [parameter space](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52012/156) of neural networks, where each sample point is a paper. That's a waste of time, really.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Hundreds? I think there's been over 100,000 papers on high-T_c superconductivity already...

Comment: @Marco13 I mean subsequent papers. Not in the same original paper.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but explainability being a criterion does not mean that non-explainable results should be excluded. It just means that explainable results should be given extra-merit

Comment: @David Agreed, and edited to make clear.

Comment: @Ryan_L If an algorithm repeatedly and reliably works in a real-world setting, that's sufficient information to say it works. False positives are part of the assessment of an algorithm. Understanding how an algorithm works can be very useful in improving it, but is not necessary to evaluate *how well* it works.

Comment: I fully agree. But I'm also with @Marco13 in that validation in many (including biomedical) studies isn't as rigorous as the claims would demand.

Comment: @cbeleites I agree that validation is often not as rigorous as it should be, but I think a lot of times that's more an issue with interpretation, not the results themselves. I think (hope) most scientists understand that a single publication is not *proof* and that *proof* really doesn't exist in science, only accumulation of evidence to the point that it becomes progressively less likely that future work will upend the status quo.

Comment: This answer and its reasoning is the reason we have less than 30% reproducibility rate in biomedical sciencs (machine learning likely similar), where researchers can often neither explain exactly how they produced the results nor why. **This is the current desaster**. As mostly CS guys are frequenting this site it shows how flawed the methodolgy/rigor/explainability is in statistical sciences and peer review as expressed in comments above. The upvoters (large majority) think really this way, this is shocking to me, not the answer so much, which had to posted by someone.

Comment: @sera What would you do about paracetamol? Anesthetics? Anti-depressants? (we don't know how any of those work) I maybe shouldn't have included the ML example but did because I thought it would be more relevant to OP's interests, but I wrote the answer with medical science in mind, going back long before ML. (and maybe read the second-to-last paragraph, too)

Comment: @BryanKrause I really think biomed cannot be the standard here with so low reproducibility and Bayer, BASF researched this fact in several meta studies. The interesting question to me is if in Anesthetics etc. science is really based on pure random trial and error and if you can then still call it science, do peer review of papers and funding proposals and spend billions every year on unreproducible research. This is sure not the case in hard sciences like physics that there is nearly zero explainability how and why dinstinct results are produced. Maybe I post such a question when I have time

Comment: how common pure random trial and error research and publications really are. Maybe I'm strongly anaware of it in biomed as a physicist. But reproducibility is the most important criterion if you want to call it science, otherwise the voters don't understand and would also argue for homeopathy instead of Anti-depressants? :-)

Comment: @sera My point is that *we know* anesthetics work, going back to the use of ether in the 1800s. Give someone an anesthetic in the proper dose, and they are unconscious, unresponsive, and have no memory of a surgical procedure (yet wake up after). No idea how it works. Now we know some of the molecular targets; still don't know why it works. We *know* anti-depressants work (and homeopathy doesn't). We even know some of their molecular targets, but we don't know which ones are important for the effect. Explanation isn't necessary to be useful.

Comment: @BryanKrause sure, but this justs shifts the problem slightly. Usefulness cannot be the goal of epistemological research, a PhD thesis or a bigger fundamental research project. Also vodoo medicine by aborigines in the forests is working somehow better than homeopathy, but can/would you call this science? You know it works over molecules, in machine learning they often have no clue what the nonlinear complex neural network does at all...

Answer (score 11):

Papers are evaluated on a variety of criteria, including accessibility and the contribution to the field of research.

Now papers that not only report findings, but analyze findings and provide root causes for effects observed in the paper are obviously more valuable and are more likely to be accepted.

But from a scientific point of view, *requiring* that papers have this property would not be a good idea. Quite often, the root cause of an observed phenomenon is not known. Not being able to publish papers without finding the root cause would mean that information stays "unknown" until the person making a discovery also finds out the reason for an observed phenomenon, which could mean that it is never found out. For instance, if Mendel with his discovery that traits are inherited until the DNA was found, 
 that would have been quite a loss.

In computer science, you need to distinguish between pure theoretical computer and the rest. While in the former, the proofs provide all the reason you need, in the applied fields, at least part of the argument is some utility of the finding. There are many subfields in which algorithms are published that work well in practice despite not giving theoretical guarantees that they always work. Finding out why certain algorithms work well in practice would require to define exactly what "practice" means, which changes over time. Machine learning is a good example: we know that many machine learning algorithms can get stuck in local optima, and we have some ideas on how to prevent that (in many interesting cases). And then there is some theory that tries to capture this. But ultimately, the reason for why many of the approaches work are that the models to be learned are easy enough and the algorithm is good enough, which is very difficult to  impossible to formalize to a level that it would be acceptable in a scientific paper. And then requiring an in-depth explanation of why a new approach works would essentially mean that there will be almost no publications of practical relevance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by explainability and it cannot be a scientific metric if it doesn't exist in a dictionary.

So I conclude what you are thinking about is that the content of an article has to explain something: an not well understood process, a new method, a new theory.

Different fields have different standards and metrics. I'm sure there are different for publishing a new physical theory vs. an optimization of a machine learning algorithm for image recognition. But this is normally covered by the novelty and significance metric by a journal.

From a philosophy of science point of view you also should see or inspect what the modus operandi of researchers in your field is. For example, in particle physics or cosmology researchers try to falsify the scientific paradigm/theory, especially if there are too many flaws in a currently used theory. I know some of the basics of machine learning theory and that many of it is based on mathematical methods developed in quantum physics. This is a bullet-proof theory pretty much, no one has falsified it until this day and physicists still try. But in engineering and even in applied physics depending on the topic/resarch question rather a positivistic modus operandi is used by researchers, e.g. optimizing/enhancing/backing up a machine learning algorithm without substantial questioning or falsification underlying theories. And for minor incremental improvements an explanation in the sense of why rather then how may be not necessary in your field and therefore no general metric if the underlying theories are not really touched. As soon as you question a theory or common measurement process, at least in physics, you need to input a good explanation in your article, why and how you do this. What is the motivation, why it is more accurate to describe something.

When you say in the comment "proving something works without how it works", I think this is what sometimes in industrial machine learning happens, input - black box - output. But if you can neither explain how or why your algorithm works (better), in the best case you can call it smart engineering but not science that can/should be published ;-)

Comment: "My black-box model predicted this transaction is fraudulent" is an unexpalinable result. "My model predicted this transaction is fraudulent because there were 100 similar transactions in the last few minutes which also came from town X, most of them being for an amount in the [Y,Z] range and being cancelled seconds before...." is an explainable (and explaind) result

Answer (score 0):

Explanations are maybe not always as useful as you are probably thinking.

On the one hand, say, a mathematical proof why this machine learning approach behaves the way it does is fine. As long as the proof is correct, this type of explanation will never become wrong (only maybe outdated).

On the other hand, consider complex systems as you encounter them in the life sciences. An explanation in a paper would often really not be at the level of a mathematical proof (that level of certainty is *impossible* to obtain in the natural sciences), it would be a plausible hypothesis in line with the experimental findings.
 The catch is: had the experimental findings been different, very often (sufficiently complex system) plausible "explanations" could be formulated which would be contradictory to the plausible explanation formulated for the findings actually at hand.
In that sense, explanations (hypotheses fitted retrospectively) are a dime a dozen.

Personally, I think it more important to limit the claims to what the data in the paper can actually support. Iff you bring good data that shows your model successfully deals with the situation at hand, that's fine. And coming from an experimental field, I'd still ask for a proper and honest experimental support (which is more than a quick verification with a few not-so-independent cases*) alongside any explanation.
And: Just as validation may be wrong in that a major influencing factor was overlooked/unknown at the time of the study, wrong/mistaken explanations have been known as well.

All that being said, this may be too much for a single paper - so IMHO it's fine to publish "advances in theory" and "experimental findings for this application" papers (as long as each of the papers has sufficient substance on its own).

---

* if you take the time a well designed validation study with, say, 3000 patients needs to work towards a deeper mathematical/theoretical understanding, you may get quite far in that respect as well...